# How do you disable Ursina FirstPersonController?

Tags: python, ursina

I want to do a game with 3D sections and some with a static camera. I implemented the FirstPersonController and it is working fine but I cannot find any way to disable it (if on_disable() is supposed to do this I cannot make it work) Therefore, I tried to simply delete it and set it up again as needed.

Setting up the 3D player

```
player = FirstPersonController
```

Deleting the 3D player

```
player.eternal = False
player.children = []
destroy(player)
player = Empty
```

For some reason however, the game continues to act as if FirstPersonController is still in use despite showing that the player was destroyed. Can anyone tell me if there is something I'm missing to delete the controller or a simpler way to disable it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would very much suggest that you ask questions about ursina engine in their [discord server](https://discord.com/invite/ydXfhyb)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it like this:

```
player.enabled = False
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It's working perfectly now